# Best Way to output SoyTemplates from a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, google-closure-templates

What is the best waya to render or output Soy Templates from closure-templates to a browser?

Currently i have the following:
    package de.envisia.erp.web.servlet;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.google.template.soy.SoyFileSet;

import com.google.template.soy.tofu.SoyTofu;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class EntryPoint
 */
@WebServlet("/EntryPoint")
public class EntryPoint extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public EntryPoint() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext();
    String pathContext = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
    //response.getWriter().println(pathContext);

    SoyFileSet sfs = new SoyFileSet.Builder().add(new File(pathContext + "\\templates\\hello.soy")).build();
    SoyTofu tofu = sfs.compileToTofu();
    String out = tofu.newRenderer("hello.world").render();
    response.getWriter().println(out);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

But i don't think it is a good practice to use the println or even print() method of the response object, are there any better ways?

Comment: why not use the write method. however, the weakness in your code lies in that you are compiling the template on each request, that is going to be extremely slow.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/codedance/silken.

The basic idea is to make a special servlet and forward requests to it:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/soy/products.boat.sailingBoatView");
rd.forward(req, resp);
```